# Load .svg File from filepath to ImageView

Tags: android, svg, imageview

Hi Everyone How can i import svg extension file from filepath in ImageView

I am using this library https://github.com/Templarian/MaterialDesign for 5600+ material icons

I have a gridview to show 5600+ icons

In the customview of gridview i added a imageview to show icons there

I have a folder in  named as */svg/*my 5600+ svg files**

Please help me i request you

Comment: Are you using kotlin? If so you can use `coil`

Comment: No i am using java